# Unknown extra margin

Tags: html, css

I have a few div elements, that I want to align with 20px margin. However when I set my margin to 20px, there are additional 4 pixels rendered.
Here is the code:

```
.block{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

*{
    margin:0
    padding:0
    border-width:0px;
}
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/zyfzbyed/8/ with inspector.
The question is: *How can i remove that extra margin?*
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your HTML use

```
<div class='block'></div><div class='block'></div>
```

instead of

```
<div class='block'>

</div>
<div class='block'>

</div>
```

if you want to fix this via CSS you should set div's flow to `left` as follow

```
.block{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:0px;
    vertical-align:top;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: That removes the problem but doesn't solve it. To learn, read more on the dupe link above.

Comment: Oh, so the problem was additional space in HTML. Thanks.

Comment: @JakaKordež yes of course, everything depend on how to use of your classes

Answer (score -1):

You can add `float:left;` to `.block` in CSS to remove the extra-margins created by inline-block element. your css for block should be:

```
.block{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:0px;
  vertical-align:top;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: That removes the problem but doesn't solve it. To learn, read more on the dupe link above.